# image uploads in tornado web server

Tags: python, file-upload, tornado

i'm trying to get a simple image upload form going in tornado.  it all works fine with text files, the data is getting to the server and being written out to the filesystem.  however, when i try to upload a binary file (jpeg or png, specifically) it gets corrupted.  opening the result of an uploaded PNG results in the error "PNG file corrupted by ascii conversion" and jpeg gives "jpeg datastream contains no image".  what am i doing wrong?

python:

```
class FileUploadHandler(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
    reg=self.get_argument('regid', None)
    self.write(dir(self.request.files['myfile'][0]))
    if reg:
        reg=Registration(id=reg)
        f=open(ROOT_APP_PATH+'/static/clubfiles/{0}/{1}/{2}'\
            .format(reg.club.id, reg.id, uuid()), 'w')
        f.write(self.request.files['myfile'][0]['body'])
        f.close()
```

html:

```
   <form    target=iframe 
            action="/do_file_upload/" 
            enctype="multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8"
            method="post">
        <input type=hidden name=regid value=${element.get_relevant_registration().id}>
        <input name=myfile type=file onchange="$(this).parent().submit()">
    </form>
```

the tornado server is running on win server 2008, if that's relevant.

edit: dammit, simple fix.  i needed to use open(filename, 'wb') to write in binary mode.  hope this helps somebody who lands here from google.

Comment: eight and a half years after being closed as "unlikely to help any future visitors" i still get a chuckle every time stackoverflow notifies me that somebody has upvoted this.